# How to specify foreign keys to a table in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I take Trains as one table and passenger as other table.
train table has train_no, train_name.
Passenger table has pnr and train_no.
i would like to create train_no as foreign key in passengers table.
please provide sufficient code for it..
i am rookie in it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Parse.com has ample documentation to do this, with tutorials/helper code for managing relationships. You also don't even state which language you'd like the code in.

Comment: I am using parse with android.

Answer (score 3):

Parse is MongoDB like **Object DBMS**.

Concept of **FK constraints** is not available in Parse.

In order to use referencing you have to use **Pointers**. Although you can write some code for having FK constraint satisfaction (One easy option for the same is to use **[beforeSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers)** feature of Cloud Code.)